# Nonparametric MANOVA in R

Tags: r

I need to do a nonparametric test on data I have, particularly a non-parametric version of MANOVA in r.  Does anyone know how to be able to perform a non-parametric test in R, particularly what the coding is, and what package to use?  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

## Permutational MANOVA

```
require(vegan)
?adonis
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
install.packages("sos")
library("sos")
findFn("nonparametric anova")
```

Then you can read through some of the help pages that will be displayed.  Some of them might do manova (a search for 'nonparametric manova' returned only one hit).

Comment: `findFn("nonparametric multivariate anova")` is more specific but still promising

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found, using the `adonis` function from `vegan` on some random generated data:

```r
dframetest <- data.frame(X = rnorm(20), Y = rnorm(20), Z = rnorm(20), Label = c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10)))

adonis(dframetest[,1:3] ~ Label, permutations = 1000, data = dframetest, method = "euclidean")
```

The output looks like this:

```
Call:
adonis(formula = dframetest[, 1:3] ~ Label, data = dframetest,      permutations = 1000, method = "euclidean") 

Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 1000

Terms added sequentially (first to last)

          Df SumsOfSqs MeanSqs F.Model      R2 Pr(>F)
Label      1     1.747  1.7467 0.58834 0.03165 0.6334
Residuals 18    53.438  2.9688         0.96835       
Total     19    55.184                 1.00000
```

I changed the parameters of course to fit my own data, but this si a good example

Keep in mind that this test runs on permutations of data (as it is a non-parametric test and cannot just run without it)

Credit should go to this question from @antsushi: [Why does adonis() from vegan returns a different p-value every time it is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56938448/why-does-adonis-from-vegan-returns-a-different-p-value-every-time-it-is)